# Add extension attribute to Order

Tags: magento2, sales-order, extension-attributes

I want to add custom field "comment" to the order as an extension attribute. So, the first, I have added this column to following tables in database: "quote" and "sales_order".

It's my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="comment" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

It's my observer ("sales_order_save_after"), where I'm trying to set "comment":

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

class SaveComment implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_rep;

    public function __construct(OrderRepositoryInterface $rep)
    {
        $this->_rep = $rep;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
        $ext = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $ext->setComment('Hi, Magento!');
        $order->setExtensionAttributes($ext);
        $this->_rep->save($order);
    }
}
```

And it works, but doesn't add any attributes to database, so when I try to get it in another place with:

```
$comment = $order->getExtensionAttributes()->getComment();
```

I get null.
Please, help me.

Comment: You must not add new columns to existing core table, you should create own tables instead. And in that case, you need to retrieve extension attributes from another table, as an example https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Vault/Plugin/PaymentVaultAttributesLoad.php how to achieve it.

Comment: Accept the answer If you find my answer helpful @Skorzhyk

Comment: Link in the comments is dead. Any chance on a new one? I keep seeing this link everywhere.

Comment: Make sure to delete the generations folder.

Comment: @JNDPNT I've added an answer with an updated link

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the below plugin to di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="get_order_comment" type="Vendor\Sample\Plugin\OrderGet"/>
</type>
```

Now add the plugin to add the data to the api

```
class OrderGet {

    protected $_orderExtensionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtensionFactory $orderExtensionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_orderExtensionFactory = $orderExtensionFactory;
    }

    public function afterGet(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface $subject,
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    ) {
        $extensionAttributes = $order->getExtensionAttributes();
        $orderExtension = $extensionAttributes ? $extensionAttributes : $this->_orderExtensionFactory->create();

        $comment = {write the logic to get the comment. e.g. $order->getComment()}
        $orderExtension->setComment($comment);

        $order->setExtensionAttributes($orderExtension);

        return $order;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add extension attributes in Magento 2 Order data by creating a**extension_attributes.xml** file under etc folder.

Get insight into extension attributes in Magento 2 by referring blog,

[Magento 2 Order Extension Attribute](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/extension-attribute-in-order-data-magento-2/)

add code,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface">
        <attribute code="order_comment" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Comment: How can we use order extension attribute with custom total(row) model ?

Comment: Links can become stale and broken; please consider adding the critical information from the linked resource to your post

Answer (score 0):

The dead link in the comments refers to a branch which is no longer available.

Here is a permalink which points to the `2.4` branch: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/33242e4b19cf207d7b73f7791ef894b48bb41f8a/app/code/Magento/Vault/Plugin/PaymentVaultAttributesLoad.php

...and because posting links in comments is bad practice for Stack Exchange sites, here is the content of that file:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Magento\Vault\Plugin;

use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentExtensionInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentInterface;
use Magento\Vault\Api\PaymentTokenManagementInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderPaymentExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Vault\Api\Data\PaymentTokenInterface;

/**
 * Plugin for loading vault payment extension attribute to order/payment entity
 */
class PaymentVaultAttributesLoad
{
    /**
     * @var OrderPaymentExtensionFactory
     */
    protected $paymentExtensionFactory;

    /**
     * @var PaymentTokenManagementInterface
     */
    protected $paymentTokenManagement;

    /**
     * @param OrderPaymentExtensionFactory $paymentExtensionFactory
     * @param PaymentTokenManagement|PaymentTokenManagementInterface $paymentTokenManagement
     */
    public function __construct(
        OrderPaymentExtensionFactory $paymentExtensionFactory,
        PaymentTokenManagementInterface $paymentTokenManagement
    ) {
        $this->paymentExtensionFactory = $paymentExtensionFactory;
        $this->paymentTokenManagement = $paymentTokenManagement;
    }

    /**
     * Load vault payment extension attribute to order/payment entity
     *
     * @param OrderPaymentInterface $payment
     * @param OrderPaymentExtensionInterface|null $paymentExtension
     * @return OrderPaymentExtensionInterface
     */
    public function afterGetExtensionAttributes(
        OrderPaymentInterface $payment,
        OrderPaymentExtensionInterface $paymentExtension = null
    ) {
        if ($paymentExtension === null) {
            $paymentExtension = $this->paymentExtensionFactory->create();
        }

        $paymentToken = $paymentExtension->getVaultPaymentToken();
        if ($paymentToken === null) {
            $paymentToken = $this->paymentTokenManagement->getByPaymentId($payment->getEntityId());
            if ($paymentToken instanceof PaymentTokenInterface) {
                $paymentExtension->setVaultPaymentToken($paymentToken);
            }
            $payment->setExtensionAttributes($paymentExtension);
        }

        return $paymentExtension;
    }
}
```