# How do you send additional attributes to order using /rest//V1/guest-carts/{cart-id}/order REST API Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, place-order

I have successfully placed order by creating cart and finally calling rest api `/rest//V1/guest-carts/{cart-id}/order` to place the order. Now I am trying to add an additional attribute custom_attribute to be displayed on orders table page of admin dashboard but am unable to figure out the way around.

I have tried to extend the magento functionality using following link but somehow cannot set custom attribute via rest api

https://www.yereone.com/blog/magento-2-how-to-add-new-order-attribute/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with help of **extension attributes** , here is magento documentation how to add an extension attribute https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

There are also some stack questions that you can refer to

[Add extension attribute to Order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194653/add-extension-attribute-to-order)

and some good articles
https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/extension-attribute-in-order-data-magento-2/

Comment: I am unable to get this line working:
$orderComment = $order->getData(self::FIELD_NAME);
as given in the article
I am calling the api : /rest//V1/guest-carts/{cart-id}/order and passing 'order_comment' in request but somehow unable to access it here.

Comment: Share in question , the code you have tried